# How can I modify the response.content in a Django Middleware __call__ method

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to remove all blank lines in xml response by processing it in a middleware as suggested in this example: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/StripWhitespaceMiddleware
Now the problem is that in Django 2.1 that code is no more current since Dajngo 1.10 the way the Middleware works changed quite a bit.
Now I see that the response.content is of type bytes and so no straightforward editable with regex.
What is the correct way to do this in Django 1.10+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your said, `response.content` is a `bytes` so all arguments in the regex have to by of type `byte`, including the replacement string.

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.whitespace = re.compile(b'^\s*\n', re.MULTILINE)
        #self.whitespace_lead = re.compile(b'^\s+', re.MULTILINE)
        #self.whitespace_trail = re.compile(b'\s+$', re.MULTILINE)


    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if "text" in response['Content-Type']:
        #Use next line instead to avoid failure on cached / HTTP 304 NOT MODIFIED responses without Content-Type
        #if response.status_code == 200 and "text" in response['Content-Type']:
            if hasattr(self, 'whitespace_lead'):
                response.content = self.whitespace_lead.sub(b'', response.content)
            if hasattr(self, 'whitespace_trail'):
                response.content = self.whitespace_trail.sub(b'\n', response.content)
            if hasattr(self, 'whitespace'):
                response.content = self.whitespace.sub(b'', response.content)
            return response
        else:
            return response
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> Both patterns and strings to be searched can be Unicode strings (str)
>   as well as 8-bit strings (bytes). **However, Unicode strings and 8-bit
>   strings cannot be mixed**: that is, you cannot match a Unicode string
>   with a byte pattern or vice-versa; similarly, **when asking for a
>   substitution, the replacement string must be of the same type as both
>   the pattern and the search string.**

Comment: Thanks I'll try that approach, I was decoding it to str and reencoding it to be able to do the substitutions